# How to create custom view, which I create in code, but set its parameters in its XML layout resource

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-custom-view

I have this custom layout called semesterCardView. Because it is quite complex and I ran into some "onMeasure taking damn too long" issues I need to somehow flatten its hierarchy.

I instantiate the layout form XML, its called in adapter. In constructor I call this:

```
View.inflate(context, R.layout.semester_card_layout, this);
```

The layout resource looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/semesterInfo"
          android:visibility="visible"
          android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
          android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
          android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/card_ui_bg"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/information"
    android:id="@+id/card_title"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    style="@style/Theme.Kosapp.Text.Light"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Large"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/main_kosapp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/card_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">


</LinearLayout>

<ViewStub
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout="@layout/zero_courses_label"
    android:inflatedId="@+id/zeroCoursesMarker"
    android:id="@+id/zeroCoursesMarker"/>
```

The problem I want to solve is, that in although my custom view already should serve like a linear layout (its extending from it), in the resulting layout hierarchy, it has actually only one child - the top level linear layout from my layout resource file. I have tried to use merge tag instead of linearlayout..That could solve that issue, but I would like to preserve those layout params which are set in XML..(just because they are in DIPs)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<merge>` tag along with all those attributes in your current `<LinearLayout>` tag.

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/semesterInfo"
      android:visibility="visible"
      android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
      android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="@drawable/card_ui_bg"
>

<!-- card_title and card_content  -->

</merge>
```

Comment: for me it looks like those params are not applied to the parent (merged) layout..